# Tener otra tabla en un console.table

Tags: javascript, nodejs

resulta que tengo que hacer un excel y uso console.table para traer la información como se veria en un excel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta imagen es una simple tabla el codigo es:

```
   const prueba = [
    {
        name: 'Juan', edad: '20',
    },
    {
        name: 'Pedro', edad: '30',
    },
    {
        hobbies: 'mi hobbie', detalle: 'detalles',
    }
]
 console.table(prueba)
```

pero lo que yo quiero hacer es que me salga otra columna aparte, ejemplo:

```
┌─────────┬─────────┬──────┬
│ (index) │  name   │ edad │ 
├─────────┼─────────┼──────┼
│    0    │ 'Juan'  │ '20' │ 
│    1    │ 'Pedro' │ '30' │   
│    2    │         │      │
└─────────┴─────────┴──────┴
│   hobbies   │  detalle   │
├─────────────┼────────────┼
│             │            │
│             │            │
│ 'mi hobbie' │ 'detalles' │
└─────────────┴────────────┴
```

Comment: De por sí la consola es bastante limitada, no creo que `console.table` te de tanta flexibilidad. Supongo que tendrás que usar librerías de terceros.

Comment: Con console.table es complicado, puedes separar la data y luego hacer 2 **table** algo así https://jsfiddle.net/mL6qzjeo/1/

Comment: y como hago eso mismo pero a un excel que me salga la data impresa así

Comment: Si necesitas que este objeto sea cargado por alguna planilla de cálculos  podrías convertir el objeto a csv.